# Recovering a Log-Correlated Gaussian Field from a limit-lognormal singular measure

Tags: pr.probability, mathematical-finance

In a paper I (didn't write, but) co-authored, *Forecasting Volatility with the Multifractal Random Walk Model*, we use explicit formulas that give the law of $(X(t),t>0)$ conditional on $(X(t),t<0)$ for a "log-correlated Gaussian" (generalised) process, i.e. centered with $\mathbb E\int X(t)\varphi_1(t)\ dt\int X(s)\varphi_2(s)\ ds=c\int \varphi_1(t)\varphi_2(s)\log(1/|t-s|)\ dt\ ds$, $\int\varphi_1=\int\varphi_2=0$.

To apply this to volatility forecasting, one needs to recover $(X(t), t<0)$ from a sample, which, in said model, is (the restriction to $(-\infty,0)$ of) the **limit**-lognormal random measure $\mu$ associated to $X$, defined as $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}e^{X_\varepsilon(t)-\frac12\mathbb EX_\varepsilon(t)^2}\ dt$ where $X_\varepsilon$ is smooth and $\to X$.

This raises the **question**: is information lost in $X\mapsto\mu$, due to the singularity of $\mu$, or do the $\sigma$-algebras generated, respectively, by $\mu$ and by $X$, coincide ?

Comment: In the two dimensional case, this has been answered in the affirmative by Berestycki Sheffield and Sun https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.5407.pdf
I suspect that the proof in section 3 of that paper carries over to the one dimensional case, if you replace $h_\epsilon$ appropriately.